# Java Logic Issue

Tags: java, swing

I just got my rock, paper, scissors, lizard, Spock done (Big Bang Theory joke); but when I run it and try anything with either lizard or Spock, the answer is nothing near correct. This occurred with basic rock, paper, scissors, but was corrected when I changed all of the logic to "else if" statements.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

public class RPS extends JFrame {

    ButtonGroup P1choices, P2choices;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new RPS();
    }

    public RPS() {
        super("Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock");

        setSize(400, 400);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

        final CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout(10, 10);
        final JPanel cardPanel = new JPanel(cardLayout);

        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();

        final JRadioButton P1Rock = new JRadioButton("Rock");
        final JRadioButton P1Paper = new JRadioButton("Paper");
        final JRadioButton P1Scissors = new JRadioButton("Scissors");
        final JRadioButton P1Lizard = new JRadioButton("Lizard");
        final JRadioButton P1Spock = new JRadioButton("Spock");

        final JRadioButton P2Rock = new JRadioButton("Rock");
        final JRadioButton P2Paper = new JRadioButton("Paper");
        final JRadioButton P2Scissors = new JRadioButton("Scissors");
        final JRadioButton P2Lizard = new JRadioButton("Lizard");
        final JRadioButton P2Spock = new JRadioButton("Spock");

        JButton nextButton = new JButton("Next");
        JButton finish = new JButton("Finish");

        P1choices = new ButtonGroup();
        P1choices.add(P1Rock);
        P1choices.add(P1Paper);
        P1choices.add(P1Scissors);
        P1choices.add(P1Lizard);
        P1choices.add(P1Spock);

        P2choices = new ButtonGroup();
        P2choices.add(P2Rock);
        P2choices.add(P2Paper);
        P2choices.add(P2Scissors);
        P2choices.add(P2Lizard);
        P2choices.add(P2Spock);

        final JLabel statusLabel = new JLabel(" ");
        JLabel P1turn = new JLabel("It is Player 1's turn. Choose:");
        JLabel p2turn = new JLabel("It is Player 2's turn. Choose:");

        panel1.add(P1turn);
        panel1.add(P1Rock);
        panel1.add(P1Paper);
        panel1.add(P1Scissors);
        panel1.add(P1Lizard);
        panel1.add(P1Spock);
        panel1.add(nextButton);
        panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(7, 1));

        panel2.add(p2turn);
        panel2.add(P2Rock);
        panel2.add(P2Paper);
        panel2.add(P2Scissors);
        panel2.add(P2Lizard);
        panel2.add(P2Spock);
        panel2.add(finish);
        panel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(7, 1));

        cardPanel.add(panel1);
        cardPanel.add(panel2);

        add(statusLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(cardPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        nextButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                cardLayout.next(cardPanel);
            }
        });
        finish.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (P1Rock.isSelected() && P2Scissors.isSelected()) {
                    statusLabel.setText("Player 1 wins: Rock crushes Scissors");
                } else if (P2Paper.isSelected()) {
                    statusLabel.setText("Player 2 wins: Scissors cut Paper");
                } else if (P2Rock.isSelected()) {
                    statusLabel.setText("It's a tie!");
                } else if (P2Lizard.isSelected()) {
                    statusLabel.setText("Player 1 wins: Rock crushes Lizard");
                } else if (P2Spock.isSelected()) {
                    statusLabel.setText("Player 2 wins: Spock vaporizes Rock");
                } else if (P1Paper.isSelected() && P2Rock.isSelected()) {
                    statusLabel.setText("Player 1 wins: Rock crushes Scissors");
                } else if (P2Scissors.isSelected()) {
                    statusLabel.setText("Player 2 wins: Scissors cut Paper");
                } else if (P2Paper.isSelected()) {
                    statusLabel.setText("It's a tie!");
                } else if (P2Lizard.isSelected()) {
                    statusLabel.setText("Player 2 wins: Lizard eats Paper");
                } else if (P2Spock.isSelected()) {
                    statusLabel.setText("Player 1 wins: Paper disproves Spock");
                } else if (P1Scissors.isSelected() && P2Paper.isSelected()) {
                    statusLabel.setText("Player 1 wins: Scissors cut Paper");
                } else if (P2Rock.isSelected()) {
                    statusLabel.setText("Player 2 wins: Rock crushes Scissors");
                } else if (P2Scissors.isSelected()) {
                    statusLabel.setText("It's a tie!");
                } else if (P2Lizard.isSelected()) {
                    statusLabel.setText("Player 1 wins: Scissors decapitate Lizard");
                } else if (P2Spock.isSelected()) {
                    statusLabel.setText("Player 2 wins: Spock smashes Scissors");
                } else if (P1Lizard.isSelected() && P2Spock.isSelected()) {
                    statusLabel.setText("Player 1 wins: Lizard poisons Spock");
                } else if (P2Rock.isSelected()) {
                    statusLabel.setText("Player 2 wins: Rock crushes Scissors");
                } else if (P2Scissors.isSelected()) {
                    statusLabel.setText("Player 2 wins: Scissors decapitate Lizard");
                } else if (P2Lizard.isSelected()) {
                    statusLabel.setText("It's a tie!");
                } else if (P2Paper.isSelected()) {
                    statusLabel.setText("Player 1 wins: Lizard eats Paper");
                } else if (P1Spock.isSelected() && P2Rock.isSelected()) {
                    statusLabel.setText("Player 1 wins: Spock vaporizes Rock");
                } else if (P2Paper.isSelected()) {
                    statusLabel.setText("Player 2 wins: Paper disproves Spock");
                } else if (P2Scissors.isSelected()) {
                    statusLabel.setText("Player 1 wins: Spock smashes Scissors");
                } else if (P2Lizard.isSelected()) {
                    statusLabel.setText("Player 2 wins: Lizard poisons Spock");
                } else if (P2Spock.isSelected()) {
                    statusLabel.setText("It's a tie!");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Sorry if the code is messy, and I know there are more efficient ways of doing this, but I want to at least make it work before I clean it all up.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should step through your code with a debugger to figured out why it's not behaving as you expect it to.

Comment: You might benefit from http://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882.

Comment: You should give this a better title

Comment: Could you describe the specific problem? Like where is it going wrong, etc.?

Comment: The code looks relatively ugly, but at least your question title is funny.

Comment: @Jonik relative to what? :)

Comment: Again, I apologize for the sloppiness of the code, but I'm 13, what do you expect? Anyway, I have combed through the program multiple times and cannot find anything that cause the issue. The problem is that unlike my classic rock paper scissors, all of these answers are incorrect. For example, choosing rock and paper in this version result in a tie.

Comment: @ZeroConnor: don't just go through the code, use a debugger such as is available with Eclipse or NetBeans.

Comment: @Bart: Well, there's tons of code out there whose logic is even more repetitive and unclear. :) But given OP's explanation above, maybe that's understandable after all.

Comment: @ZeroConnor: you might find someone here to debug your code, but debugging code is an important skill to learn yourself. Look at the code and think about what **should** be happening. Inspect the state with a debugger and observe how it differs from your thinking. Then think about **why** it's different. That's debugging. || On a completely different note, another thing to think about is **data representation**. We have two players and five states or values. Is there a data structure that you can use to use to look up the winner directly, instead of having to write a pile of if-statements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to nest your if-else statements like this:

```
if (P1Rock.isSelected()) {
   if (P2Scissors.isSelected()) {
     statusLabel.setText("Player 1 wins: Rock crushes Scissors");
   } else if (P2Paper.isSelected()) {
     statusLabel.setText("Player 2 wins: Scissors cut Paper");
   } else if (P2Rock.isSelected()) {
     statusLabel.setText("It's a tie!");
   } else if (P2Lizard.isSelected()) {
     statusLabel.setText("Player 1 wins: Rock crushes Lizard");
   } else if (P2Spock.isSelected()) {
     statusLabel.setText("Player 2 wins: Spock vaporizes Rock");
   }
} else if (P1Scissors.isSelected()) {
   if (P2Scissors.isSelected()) {
     ... // and so on
```

Because you firstly want to proof what Player1 selected. Then you want to check, how it fits to the other players option.

---

Furthermore some tips for you to write a much more cleaner code:

- Implement your logic before implementing the user interface (UI). So the logic is cut off from the UI. It will be much more easier to change your logic afterwards.
- Since Java is an object orientated programming (OOP) language, think about having some classes like `Rock`, `Scissors`, (and so on) which implement an interface or extend an abstract class.

Probably this will result in much more code, but if you have a new type of choice (say **Chuck**), you only have to add a new class `Chuck` and implement the beating possibilities against the other classes (like `Rock`, `Scissors`, ...).

The same goes to the UI. You should clean up your components to some arrays (buttons[0 - 4]), so you [don't have to repeat yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) by using some loop conditions (and finally, it's also easier to add **Chuck** to your army).

Comment: I wouldn't recommend nesting if-else statements like that.

Comment: Of course, there are several other possibilities in the way to solve this problem! Anyway, i just wanted to show the correct way of doing it with the OPs if-else strategy!

Comment: Could I have more information on organizing it like this @bobbel ? I am willing to try anything.

Comment: I have added some words to my answer. Hope that helps a bit going to the right direction.